# How to look up a result using vlookup with a variable as the look up value in VBA?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

How to look up a result using vlookup with a variable as the look up value in VBA?

Example:

```
Dim JobNumber

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=(VLOOKUP(JobNumber,'Job List'!C[1]:C[4],1,FALSE)
```

Comment: do you want to have access to the result of this formula in your VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as this:

```
Dim JobNumber 

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(" & JobNumber & ",'Job List'!C[1]:C[4],1,FALSE)"
```

Comment: thanks...I left off the quotation marks...should have figured that one out